# Problems add marker layer using geojson

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl

I'm learning about the mapbox js api/sdk.

I've created a map with an isochrome layer by following tutorial on mapbox site.

I'm trying to add layer for markers.  The isochrome layer appears but the markers do not.  Any ideas if anything is wrong with my addlayer()?

```
map.addLayer({
        'id:': 'hospitals',
        'type': 'symbol',
        'source': {
          'type': 'geojson',
          'data': hospitals
        },
        layout: {
          'icon-image': 'hospital-15',
          'icon-allow-overlap': true
        },
        paint: { }
      });
```

Here's my hospitals json

```
    var hospitals = {
      type: 'FeatureCollection',
      features: [
    { type: 'Feature', properties: { Name: 'VA Medical Center -- Leestown Division', Address: '2250 Leestown Rd' }, geometry: { type: 'Point', coordinates: [-84.539487, 38.072916] } },
    { type: 'Feature', properties: { Name: 'St. Joseph East', Address: '150 N Eagle Creek Dr' }, geometry: { type: 'Point', coordinates: [-84.440434, 37.998757] } },
    { type: 'Feature', properties: { Name: 'Central Baptist Hospital', Address: '1740 Nicholasville Rd' }, geometry: { type: 'Point', coordinates: [-84.512283, 38.018918] } },
    { type: 'Feature', properties: { Name: 'VA Medical Center -- Cooper Dr Division', Address: '1101 Veterans Dr' }, geometry: { type: 'Point', coordinates: [-84.506483, 38.02972] } },
     ]
  };
```

I'm adding the layers in the map onload function.

```
    map.on('load', function() {
 
 
      // When the map loads, add the source and layer
     map.addSource('iso', {
        type: 'geojson',
        data: {
          "type": 'FeatureCollection',
          "features": []
        }
      });
     
    map.addLayer({
        'id': 'isoLayer',
        'type': 'fill',
        // Use "iso" as the data source for this layer
        'source': 'iso',
        'layout': {},
        'paint': {
          // The fill color for the layer is set to a light purple
          'fill-color': '#5a3fc0',
          'fill-opacity': 0.3
        }
      }, "poi-label");

   map.addLayer({
    'id:': 'hospitals',
    'type': 'symbol',
    'source': {
      'type': 'geojson',
      'data': hospitals
    },
    layout: {
      'icon-image': 'hospital-15',
      'icon-allow-overlap': true
    },
    paint: { }
  });

     // Make the API call
      getIso();
    });
```

Comment: Is it giving any error in the console? Where are you loading the `icon-image`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `icon-image` may be the problem. Got the markers to show following [this example](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/add-image/).

```
map.on('load', function(){
    map.loadImage(
      'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7c/201408_cat.png',
      function(error, image) {
      if (error) throw error;
      map.addImage('cat', image);
    });

    map.addLayer({
      'id': 'hospitals',
      'type': 'symbol',
      'source': {
        'type': 'geojson',
        'data': hospitals
      },
      'layout': {
        'icon-image': 'cat',
        'icon-size': 0.2,
      },
    });
  });
```